# How do i check for previously made discord invites in discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Whenever this command is run, a new discord invite is made. Is there any way to make the bot check for previously made invites?

```
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite()
    sender = ctx.message.author.id
    await ctx.author.send(f"<@{sender}>, your invite link is {link}")
    await ctx.send(f"<@{ctx.message.author.id}>, an invite link has been sent to your DMs!")
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to maintain a global dict with id, link.

But the correct solution is to have a database (preferably persistent) like SQLite, MySQL, or even NoSQL databases. And save the generated link for the first time, save it, get it from the database the next time someone sends that command. 
search on google for [python database tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=python%20database%20tutorial), [example](https://realpython.com/tutorials/databases/)

Answer (score 1):

Using: `await guild.invites()` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.invites
you can get a list of all the invites in that guild really easily

Comment: Sorry to take up more of your time, but what would be the usage for this (I am kind of new to this library). How would I check that there are no invites, or send an existing invite?

Comment: await guild.invites() returns a list, which means if you print it using `print(await guild.invites()` it will print a list of all the invites, you can now extract info from this list if you want